# Pojo/Entity corresponding to json response from Azure REST API

Tags: java, json, rest, azure, cloud

I have written a java class which hits the Azure REST API's and gets me the json response. for example below-

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS",
                "tier": "Standard"
            },
            "kind": "Storage",
            "id": "/subscriptions/cc60365e-3193-xxxx-b0f6-xxxxxxx/resourceGroups/WebServer-ubuntu/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/webserverubuntudiagxxx",
            "name": "webserverubuntudiag4xx",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "location": "eastus",
            "tags": {},
            "properties": {
                "networkAcls": {
                    "bypass": "AzureServices",
                    "virtualNetworkRules": [],
                    "ipRules": [],
                    "defaultAction": "Allow"
                },
                "trustedDirectories": [
                    "50228742-xxx-4cd2-xxx-3e50b7a62xx1"
                ],
                "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": false,
                "encryption": {
                    "services": {
                        "file": {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "lastEnabledTime": "2018-03-26T15:02:26.8078850Z"
                        },
                        "blob": {
                            "enabled": true,
                            "lastEnabledTime": "2018-03-26T15:02:26.8078850Z"
                        }
                    },
                    "keySource": "Microsoft.Storage"
                },
                "provisioningState": "Succeeded",
                "creationTime": "2018-03-26T15:02:26.6359768Z",
                "primaryEndpoints": {
                    "blob": "https://webserverubuntudiagxx.blob.core.windows.net/",
                    "queue": "https://webserverubuntudiag4xx.queue.core.windows.net/",
                    "table": "https://webserverubuntudiagxx.table.core.windows.net/",
                    "file": "https://webserverubuntudiag4xx.file.core.windows.net/"
                },
                "primaryLocation": "eastus",
                "statusOfPrimary": "available"
            }
        }

    ]
}
```

My questions is: Are there any model/pojo/bean already available to map this json to java object ?

I need to map the data from above json into the java beans/pojos  to display into jsp pages, do I need to separately create custom pojos or there are any already in Azure libraries/sdk ? any suggestions?

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question yesterday or day before?

Comment: In my previous question I wanted to find specific accessors for data from AZURE apis , here I want to know the details of available POJOs where I can map that data so that I need not create my own pojos again.